# How to use- "color to alpha" in GIMP when it is grayed out?

Tags: gimp

While you try to change the background to transparent- the filter "color to alpha" is not selectable. How to get that changed.

Answer (score 36):

Well- this is more of an answer that I wanted to post- but was unable to. This is how you do it-

- Open the image in GIMP.
- In the Layers window, right click and select "Add Alpha Channel"
- From the Colors drop-down menu- select "Color to Alpha"
- Done- the pop up asks you the preset color, click OK and your image can be saved now as png with transparent background.
  I thought it would be good to answer how I figured it out. Tania

Comment: Hmm. True in 2.10, but 2.8 doesn't care and adds the alpha channel automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback on the versions. Yes, I meant for 2.10.

Comment: Adding an alpha channel alone will not permit usage of the "Color to Alpha" function if the image is in Grayscale mode.

Answer (score 13):

#### In both v2.8 and v2.10

Color-To-Alpha (as well as many tools in the Color menu) is not available in color-indexed images (typically, GIF, but also some PNG, the image mode in indicate in the title bar).

You have to change the image to RGB mode (`Image>Mode>RGB`).

However, if you go back to indexed mode,  explicitly with `Image>Mode>Indexed` or implicitly when exporting to GIF, the alpha channel becomes "binary": pixels become either fully opaque or fully transparent, and your image will be pixellated along the edges. You can mitigate this by using Filters>Web>Semi-flatten but that makes your image usable only over a specific background color.

In 2.8 you can also paint (bucket-fill, usually) in `Color Erase` mode for nearly identical results.

#### In v2.10

It appears that the new C2A tool in 2.10 won't add an alpha channel automatically like the 2.8 one did. Possibly a fixable oversight. In the mean time, in 2.10, in RGB/Grayscale images, check that you have an alpha-channel first.

In 2.10, color-to-alpha doesn't produce the same result as in 2.8 (it is normally better (the 2.8 version can produce a dark rim in some cases); but the 2.8 behavior is kept by the `Color-erase` paint mode. In addition there is also a new `Color erase` layer blend mode.